# jQuery form submit with delegate

Tags: php, jquery

I have a working jquery code to :

- Submit specific form from multiple forms having same id
- do some validation on textarea, disable submit.
- clear text and display message on success or failure.

But - i have problem displaying messages, validation message when no text are entered is displayed properly to the specific form div. but success / failure message is not showing to specific div, it always showing to the first form div.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
 $('#replytext').keyup(function() {
    if($('#replytext').val() != '') {
       $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
 });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //$("#replyForm").submit( function () {
        $('#profile-posts-updates').delegate('#replyForm', 'submit', function() {
        //if($(this).find('#replytext').val()=='')
        if(jQuery(this).children("#replytext").val()=='') {  $(this).next('#replyerror').html('Write your message to post!').css("color","red"); return false;}
         //$('#imgbtn').show();
         //$('#post').hide();
          $.post(
           'Process.php?in=DataHandler',
            $(this).serialize(),
            function(data){
            if(data === 'Success'){
                $('#replytext').val('');
                //jQuery(this).children("#replytext").val('');
                //$("#postbox").fadeOut(50);
                //$("#postbtn").fadeIn(400);
                $("#replyerror").html('Your message has been successfully posted !').css("color","green");
                //$(this).children("#replyerror:first").html('Write your message to post!').css("color","red");
                }else{
                $("#replyerror").html('There was some problem please try again!').css("color","red");
                }
            //$('#imgbtn').hide();
            //$('#post').show();
            }
          );
          return false;   
        });   
    });
```

Comment: `multiple forms having same id` -> id attribute should be unique across DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where (part of ) your problem is

"multiple forms having same id"

Each HTML DOM element MUST have a unique ID otherwise it's not valid HTML

Comment: But i believe using jquery you have a solution (workaround ?) to handle this. since mysql while loop dynamically creates form it is difficult to provide form id to each, and create jquery functions.any help would be apricated.

Comment: @user2944727, there is no "workaround" for invalid markup.  Each `id` must be unique, otherwise, use `class`.  BTW - jQuery will only recognize the _first_ instance of an `id`.